# Onchange - switching from prototype to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

is there anyway of getting the onchange to work with jquery? Right now i'm using prototype.js. What the onchange does is when either US, CA or GB is selected it shows the state dropdown box for it. basically a show / hide

```
<SELECT id='country' onchange="HandleStateApearence(this.selectedIndex, 
null, $('state_'), $('state_3'), $('state_2'), 
null, 1, 2, false)" name=add[country]>

    <OPTION value="" selected>-- Select Country --</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=US>United States</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=CA>Canada</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=GB>United Kingdom</OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    <span id='state_' style="display:none; font-weight:bold;">State:</span> 
    <SELECT id=state_2 style="DISPLAY: none" name="c_state">
    <OPTION value="" selected>-- Select Province --</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=AB>Alberta</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="BC">British Columbia</OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    <SELECT id=state_3 style="DISPLAY: none" name="u_state">
    <OPTION value="" selected>-- Select State --</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=AL>Alabama</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=AK>Alaska</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=AZ>Arizona</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown the definition of `HandleStateAppearence()`, so I'm not sure what its parameters' expected types are, but in jQuery the `$('someselectorhere')` function returns a jQuery object that you can treat as if it is an array elements that matched the selector (potentially an empty array, though it won't be in your case). Also, to select an element by ID you use "#", e.g., `$('#state_')` - jQuery selectors (mostly) follow the syntax of CSS selectors.

So putting those two points together, if your function is expecting direct references to the select elements you need to say `$('#state_')[0]`:

```
<SELECT id='country' onchange="HandleStateApearence(this.selectedIndex, null,
         $('#state_')[0], $('#state_3')[0], $('#state_2')[0], null, 1, 2, false)"
         name=add[country]>
```

**EDIT: Here's a complete jQuery-based method to handle the show/hide of applicable state select elements.**

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#country").change(function() {
      $(".state").hide();

      var stateSelect = $("#state_" + $(this).val());

      if (stateSelect.length === 0)
         $("#state_label").hide();
      else {
         $("#state_label").show();
         stateSelect.show();
      }       
   });    
}); 
</script>

<SELECT id='country' name=add[country]>    
   <OPTION value="" selected>-- Select Country --</OPTION>
   <OPTION value=US>United States</OPTION>
   <OPTION value=CA>Canada</OPTION>
   <OPTION value=GB>United Kingdom</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<span id='state_label' style="display:none; font-weight:bold;">State:</span> 
<SELECT id="state_CA" class="state" style="DISPLAY: none" name="c_state">
   <OPTION value="" selected>-- Select Province --</OPTION>
   <OPTION value=AB>Alberta</OPTION>
   <OPTION value="BC">British Columbia</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<SELECT id="state_US" class="state" style="DISPLAY: none" name="u_state">
   <OPTION value="" selected>-- Select State --</OPTION>
   <OPTION value=AL>Alabama</OPTION>
   <OPTION value=AK>Alaska</OPTION>
   <OPTION value=AZ>Arizona</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

I've removed the inline onchange handler and instead assigned the change handler via jQuery, done inside the document.ready handler so that we can be sure the country element has already been parsed. This is the standard way to assign event handlers.

In your html, I've given each state select element a class of "state" so that we can easily select them all at once to hide them with a single statement.

I've also changed the ID attribute of the select elements to be "state_{countrycode}", e.g., "state_CA", where the codes match exactly with the corresponding values in the country option elements. That way we can reference them in JavaScript by concatenating the currently selected country code to the end of "state_" and if you later add more countries to the list with their own corresponding state drop-down you won't need to change the JavaScript at all. The most important line of code is probably this one:

```
var stateSelect = $("#state_" + $(this).val());
```

Which declares a variable `stateSelect` that will be assigned to a jQuery object containing all elements that match a selector that is an element ID of "state_{currentcountrycode}". Depending on which country option is selected that `stateSelect` jQuery object will contain exactly 0 or 1 elements, so I then test the length of the object and if it is 0 I hide the state label (I changed its ID too, to be more descriptive), or if the length is 1 I show the state label and the select element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed with prototype.js, but what it looks like you're doing is passing in elements to your `change` handler function.

In jQuery, if you're going to be selecting using IDs, you have to prepend the id value with a `#`.

```
HandleStateApearence(
    this.selectedIndex, null, 
    $('#state_'), $('#state_3'), $('#state_2'), 
    null, 1, 2, false
)
```